# Merging 2 associative arrays into 1

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm having trouble merging my arrays and not sure what I'm doing wrong. Consider the following code:

```
$array1 = [
    [ 'job' => '123', 'who' => 'Alpha' ],
    [ 'job' => '789', 'who' => 'Bravo' ]
];

$array2 = [
    [ 'job' => '123', 'when' => 'Today' ]
];

$desiredArray = [
    [ 'job' => '123', 'who' => 'Alpha', 'when' => 'Today' ],
    [ 'job' => '789', 'who' => 'Bravo', 'when' => '' ]
];
```

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($array2 as $row) {
    foreach ($array1 as $record) {
        if ($row['job'] === $record['job']) {
            $tempArray = [
                'when' => $row['when']
            ];
            $newRecord = array_merge($record, $tempArray);
            array_push($newArray, $newRecord);
        };
    };
};
```

This kinda works, but the problem is when there isn't a match, it still needs to put the original record into my new array. I've tried putting some stuff outside the if statement, but my loops are getting stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you extract arrays with `job` as the key it is much easier. Just loop the first array and check for the same key in the second and merge:

```
$a1 = array_column($array1, null, 'job');
$a2 = array_column($array2, null, 'job');

foreach($a1 as $key => $val) {
    $result[] = isset($a2[$key]) ? $val + $a2[$key] : $val;
}
```

Or the same with a built-in:

```
$result = array_replace_recursive(array_column($array1, null, 'job'),
                                  array_column($array2, null, 'job'));
```

If you need to re-index from that:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: This is the best answer by far!

Comment: Best answer, all it needs is replacing the loop by `array_replace_recursive($a1, $a2)`

Comment: @Ayaou: Great idea!  How do I give you an award?

Answer (score 3):

I think you reversed the loop, I also added an `$exist` variable to check if an item from `$array1` doesn't exists in `$array2` (So i can add it)

```
  foreach ($array1 as $row) {
        $exists = false;
        foreach ($array2 as $record) {
            if ($row['job'] === $record['job']) {
                $tempArray = [
                    'when' => $record['when']
                ];
                $newRecord = array_merge($row, $tempArray);
                array_push($newArray, $newRecord);
                $exists =true;
            };
        }; 
        if(!$exists ){
            array_push($newArray, $row);    
        }
    };
```

Comment: Also this assumes that `when` is the only new key, not very extensible.

Comment: I like this answer because it's the approach I was trying to take and you showed me the missing part I needed, but I'm going to test the other answers to see what's truly the best. I will mark this as the answer though if the others don't pan out.

Comment: @Waxi A nested `foreach()` is rarely the way to go (obviously dependent on the size of the array but still). Abra's answer is probably the best as he (or she) is only testing a certain element of the array on each iteration which in turn is a lot more resource friendly.

Comment: I recommend @AbraCadaver answer, It's the best one so far !

Answer (score 2):

Start from one of the 2 arrays and merge with the other. Flag what's not found:

```
$newArray = $array1;

foreach ($array2 as $row) { //You need to eventually deal with all of these somehow
    $found = false;
    foreach ($newArray as $key => $record) {
        if ($row['job'] === $record['job']) {
            $found = true;
            $newArray[$key] += $row; //Merge if found
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
       $newArray[] = $row; //Append if not found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the when key in the array1, you can do it like this way.

```
$jobs_time = array_combine(array_column($array2, 'job'), array_column($array2, 'when'));
$result = array_map(function($v)use($jobs_time){
    $v['when'] = isset($jobs_time[$v['job']]) ? $jobs_time[$v['job']] : '';
    return $v;
}, $array1);
```